# having issues overriding the __add__ operator to return tuples python/django

Tags: python, django, addition

I can't quite pinpoint where the problem is, could be syntax or there is something about the querysets returned by django I don't quite get.

```
Class1(models.Model):
    ...
    def __add__(self,other)
        return other + ({'attribute': value}, ..)
```

I'm hoping that the addition between classes will return 1 tuple with all the objects and put into it.
Because of that, I've had to avoid the sum() function since it's looking for integers.

```
Class Summate():
    @staticmethod
    def sum_tuples(items)
        return reduce(lambda y,x: x+y, items)


eg_list = Class1.objects.all()
values = Summate.sum_tuples(eg_list)
```

I get back an TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value.

> UPDATE: My lists were empty.  I resolved that and received this error
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'
> But shouldn't it be appending the tuple and not the dicts?

Any thoughts? Am I going about this completely wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't `eg_list` now a `QuerySet` object? You should make it a real list using `list(eg_list)`

Comment: @user334796, if you're getting that error, I can only imagine you don't have the comma after the dictionary as pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter must simply be returning no results. I just tested your code and it works.

Comment: you were right the code was fine, the list was empty and the dict error was resolved by appending a ',' after the trailing dict.  Thank you Yuji, I was going insane at one point in time =P